# Print barcode generated from URL in Shipment PDF

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, image, invoice, pdf, zend-framework

I want to insert barcode image in PDF which is generated from URL

```
eg. http:\\example.com\barcode.php?barcode=12345
```

`$pdf->drawImage()` seem not working with URL.

Any Idea How we can insert images using URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to first get the contents of the remote image and than you can add them to the pdf. Read this article: http://www.andrew-kirkpatrick.com/2012/11/using-zend_pdf-with-remote-amazon-s3-urls-files/

Comment: It means only way is, save image to local sever...